# Бинарная сериализация

Tags: c#, winforms, сериализация, десериализация

Мне необходимо была бинарная сериализация в один файл, предположим, `data.dat`

Суть файла: хранить `ключ` и `значение`

Можно ли теперь, как-нибудь, удалить ненужный ключ? Или например отредактировать. Программно.

Comment: Какая именно бинарная сериализация используется? `BinaryFormatter`? Может protobuf? Или свой собственный формат?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, `BinaryFormatter`

Comment: Тогда только так, как сказано в ответе Илюхи.

Answer (score 3):

Пусть у нас имеется сериализованный файл `data.dat` который мы хотим отредактировать.

Самое простое:

1. Выполнить десериализацию
2. Удалить значение
3. Выполнить сериализацию

В противном случае вам нужно изучать внутренние механизмы сериализации `.NET` и удалять ненужные байты по определенным смещениям, что может быть проблематично.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо.